# Java compiler error

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I have completed an assignment. However, I am unfamiliar with 
`javac` compiler error messages, and can not find an explanation 
for the following error message.

```
> ----------Compilation output--------------------------------------------
> javac Main.java
> classes in application are
> Main.java:class Main
> Main.java:class Envelope
> Letter.java:class Envelope{
> Letter.java:public class Letter {
> ./Letter.java:12: duplicate class: Envelope
> class Student{
> ^
> 1 error
```

I have no idea what to make of it and would appreciate any explanation 
of what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Could you show the source code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you have two classes called Envelope.

```
Main.java:class Envelope
Letter.java:class Envelope
```

If they are supposed to be different classes then rename one of them.

If they are supposed to be the same class then put it in is own file, rather than copy + pasting the code every time you need it.

Comment: Mark, talk about fast! Thanks for the swift response. Your assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: Mark this as the answer by pressing the tick on the left. This will help others to identify that this question has been solved. @juan